# Setting up Airbnb ESLint with React and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am trying to set up linting with Airbnb's Javascript standards on my React project, it uses webpack.

Updated with latest packages based on comments.

```
"babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
"eslint": "^3.2.2",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^10.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^1.12.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^6.0.0",
"jshint": "^2.9.2",
"jshint-loader": "^0.8.3",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
```

I also have a preloader setup in my webpack config

```
preLoaders: [
    {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['eslint'],
        // define an include so we check just the files we need
        include: PATHS.app
    }
],
```

And the following set up for running the script

```
  "lint": "eslint . --ext .js --ext .jsx --ignore-path .gitignore --cache",
```

I also have a `.eslintrc` file which has the following

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
   "env": {
      "node": true,
      "es6": true
   }
 }
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Configuration for rule "react/jsx-sort-props" is invalid:
Value "data["0"].shorthandLast" has additional properties.
```

If i remove the `.eslintrc` file which i thought might be conflicting, I get the following error:

```
 error  Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved
```

Followed by a npm error which causes the task to exit.

Comment: Have you tried it with eslint 3? There were certain recent changes and based on the error that's why it breaks. If you can't use eslint 3 yet for a reason or another, then you have to use an older version of the preset that's compatible with it.

Comment: I actually have eslint 3.9.5 install @JuhoVepsäläinen is that a late enough version?

Comment: It will pick up `"eslint": "^2.13.1",` even if you have that installed globally.

Comment: I updated my package.json to 3.9.5 and it made no difference

Comment: So now i properly fixed my version of eslint to ^3.2.2 but still the same problem.

Comment: Make sure `eslint-plugin-react` is up to date too. They released `6.0.0` just a while ago and that might fix your issue given that's where the error stems from.

Comment: Yeap i updated all the packages to the latest (removed everything and also  re-installed) Still no luck. Will update question with the latest deets

Comment: I have a working setup [here](https://github.com/survivejs/react-component-boilerplate). The biggest difference seems to be that I'm using a different parser. Hard to say anything beyond that. Maybe you could try ESLint gitter for ideas.

Comment: Looks like you haven;t added the eslintrc file to config options in webpack
`eslint: {configFile: '.eslintrc'}` could you try after adding it

Comment: I have the same issue with all updated packages, any ideas what else can I do to fix it?

Comment: @skymk i ended up having to remove all my node modules and reinstall.
Once I did that I had no problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, I had the same issue, but I fixed this error using last version of current packages:

```
"eslint": "3.2.2",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "10.0.0",
"eslint-loader": "1.5.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "1.12.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-mocha": "2.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "6.0.0",
```

And please, do this tutorial: [React Code Style with ESLint + Babel + Webpack](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-eslint-webpack-babel/)

```
module: { 
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['eslint-loader'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: path.join(__dirname, 'src/app/container')
      }
    ],
...
    eslint: {
      configFile: './.eslintrc',  //your .eslintrc file 
      emitWarning: true
    }
```

.eslintrc file

```
    {
      "extends": "airbnb"
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had to do, I had to remove all the packages and re-install too as there were some whacky conflicts!

Comment: I'm not sure about removing the global eslint or reinstalling… I did that. It actually took restarting Atom for this to go away.