# ESLint: "error Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am getting this error from ESLint:

```
error  Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved
```

from this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const _ = require('underscore');
```

I've tried removing `node_modules` and reinstalling all npm packages (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757885/setting-up-airbnb-eslint-with-react-and-webpack)), but to no avail.

Answer (score 559, accepted):

ESLint defaults to ES5 syntax-checking. You'll want to override to the latest well-supported version of JavaScript.

Try adding a `.eslintrc.json` file to your project.  Inside it:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest"
    },

    "env": {
        "es6": true
    }
}
```

See also [this example `.eslintrc.json`](https://gist.github.com/nkbt/9efd4facb391edbf8048) which might help.

Comment: These options are explained in this official documentation: Language Options - ESLint - https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options

Comment: @shuuji3 when it comes to find a solution for an error message, that documentation is useless....Even if you go through all the options, it won't tell you what triggered the error.

Comment: Sorry, I think that my intention was just to provide the official documentation URL for reference to help to understand the answer.

Comment: I had to rename the file where the const export is happening (source library) to be `.cjs` instead of `.js`.

Comment: `ecmaVersion` is not required as of today

Answer (score 33):

you also can add this inline instead of config, just add it to the same file before you add your own disable stuff

```
/* eslint-env es6 */
/* eslint-disable no-console */
```

my case was disable a file and eslint-disable were not working for me alone

```
/* eslint-env es6 */
/* eslint-disable */
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo, much easier to implement since you might not be able to easily edit your eslint config, like for scaffolded frameworks, group projects and such

Comment: /* eslint-env es2020 */ is usable too. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options list them all. Good answer, as I need it only on JS config files, the other files are TypeScript with dedicated parser.

Comment: I implemented the accepted answer, however it did not solve my problem in my karma.config.ci.js file. Only after writing ```/* eslint-env es6 */``` in the first line of code, the problem went away. Thanks!

Comment: /* eslint-env es6 */ is working fine to resolved const error but /* eslint-disable no-console */ is disabled all logs

Comment: if you need something like spread operators (which weren't usable aside from in array literals and function calls until ECMAScript 2018 (ES9)), you can add newer versions of eslint to the definition like this: `/* eslint-env es6, es2017, es2018 */`

Answer (score 18):

## Update - ESLint `v7.30.0`

With ESLint `v7.30.0`, you can use `latest` instead of `2017`, and it will enable the latest supported ECMAScript version.

> "ecmaVersion": "latest" always enables the latest supported ECMAScript
> version in ESLint's default parser.

**.eslintrc.json**

```json
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": "latest"
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I used .eslintrc.js and I have added following code.

```
module.exports = {
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    }
};
```

Answer (score 12):

If using Visual Code one option is to add this to the settings.json file:

```
"eslint.options": {
    "useEslintrc": false,
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In case none of the answers here helped, I faced a similar issue, and what I was missing from the `.eslintrc.json` file was the following:

```json
{
 "overrides": [
    {
      // rest of file...

      "files": [
        "*.ts",
        "*.js" // <- this part
      ],

       // rest of file...
 }]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I used the config in **.eslintrc.json** as mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42706706/9379687):

```
{
  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  },
  env: {
    "es6": true
  }
}
```

It was also necessary to add to **settings.json**:

```
"eslint.options": { "configFile": "eslintrc.json" }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are [migrating to ESLint's new flat config format](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide) and you only see this error in vscode when using the [official ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint), you need to manually configure it to use the new format.

From the command palette, select `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`, and add the following line:

```json
{
  "eslint.experimental.useFlatConfig": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with this part of my code:

```
const newComment = {
    dishId: dishId,
    rating: rating,
    author: author,
    comment: comment
};
newComment.date = new Date().toISOString();
```

Same error, const is a reserved word.

The thing is, I made the .eslintrc.js from the link you gave in the update and still got the same error. Also, I get an parsing error in the `.eslintrc.js`: `Unexpected token ':'`.

Right in this part:

```
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "node": true,
  "es6": true
},

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when updating. I had an eslintrc.json in the project already as well. I just closed my project in Visual Studio Code and reopened it and the error went away. It seems VS Code caches.

Answer (score -5):

In my case, it was unable to find the `.eslintrc` file so I copied from node_modules/.bin to root.