# Get object data into header (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to get my object data to header. I parse object data in my componentWillMount() and store it in navigation.setParams(userJSON: object).

My problem is I can see data in header if I just print it as JSON.stringify(object), but when I want to display it as object.name there is a problem..

### My code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const {
        setParams
    } = this.props.navigation;

    AsyncStorage.getItem('user', (err, result) => {
        this.setState({
            user: JSON.parse(result),
        });

        var obj = JSON.parse(result);

        this.props.navigation.setParams({
            userJSON: obj,
        });

    });

}
```

### Header:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: "Tab1",
    headerLeft: (
        <View style={styles.oval}>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(navigation.getParam('userJSON'))}</Text>
        </View>
    ),
    headerRight: (
      <View style={styles.headerRight}>
        <TouchableOpacity
            title="Ok"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyProfil')}>
            <View style={styles.circle}>
                <Text style={styles.txtInside}>
                {
                    navigation.getParam('userJSON').name + ''
                    + navigation.getParam('userJSON').lastname
                }
                </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
});
```

### My object is:

```
{
    id:86163
    lastname:Api
    name:Api
    email:api@eeee.com
    user:api
}
```

Comment: try this `JSON.parse(navigation.getParam('userJSON')).name`

Comment: Same error: Unexpected identifier "undefined" ....:(

Answer (score 0):

The `navigation` object has a `state` property.

You can access the `userJson` by the following way:

```
navigation.state.params.userJSON
```

On initial load of the screen, the `params` object can be `null` if there are no params, so it's better to set a small validation:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: "Tab1",
    headerLeft: {
        let username = '';
        const { state } = this.props.navigation;

        if (state.params) {
            username = state.params.userJSON.name;
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.oval}>
                <Text>{username}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    },
    headerRight: (
      ...
    )
});
```

You can check the following [issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1237).

Comment: Here is how to fix the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42706706/2765346
The quick fix is to replace `state.params` with `this.props.navigation.state.params` and to remove `const { state } = this.props.navigation;`

Comment: any errors? Try to put your logic from `componentWillMount` into `setTimeout` with a delay `0` or `1`. Please check this issue - https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1912#issuecomment-327791208

Comment: If I do that I also get null...I dont know but it seems like that header is loaded faster than componentwillmount

Comment: try to change `componentWillMount` with `componentDidMount`

Comment: I think there is problem with my header :( Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436517/couldnt-get-param-in-my-tabs/51436803?noredirect=1#comment89844501_51436803

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how i achieved this**
I was also trying to get data from AsyncStorage and setting the header title.
so my header looks like this

```
 static navigationOptions =({navigation,screenProps})=> ({
 title:typeof(navigation.state.params)==='undefined' || 
 typeof(navigation.state.params.title) === 'undefined' ? 'Loading': 
 navigation.state.params.title,
 headerTitleStyle: {textAlign:"center",alignSelf:"center"},


});
```

and in componentDidMount() you can set params like this.

```
var names = await AsyncStorage.getItem('names')
var conames =JSON.parse(names)
var name1 = conames[2]
this.props.navigation.setParams({ title: name1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use REDUX for this purpose. Hope this link helps you.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html