# Fetching data by Axios in Laravel / Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have problem about fetching data. This is error pops up in the console...

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError:
>   /var/www/html/laravel/resources/js/components/Content.vue: const is a
>   reserved word (8:4)

am I doing something wrong about the usage?

```
<template>

</template>

<script>
  export default {

    const axios = require('axios');

    axios.get('/ajax')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
    });

}
</script>
```

also in App.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


// Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('content-wrap', require('./components/Content.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706584/eslint-error-parsing-error-the-keyword-const-is-reserved

Comment: What are trying to do exactly .

Comment: I am just trying to display my data in template... @ashokpoudel But first of course trying to see it in the console...

Comment: If you are using laravel then you don't need to import axios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Laravel, so axios is allready included (take a look into the `require('/bootstrap')` file). In your component, your `export default{}` is wrong. its an object, so treat it like one:

```
export default {
  created(){
    axios.get('/ajax')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Barbie try to add `.babelrc` config file

Comment: and how am I gonna do that? could you explain a bit more, please.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first, your syntax is wrong `export default {}` exports an object but your syntax is not correct.

An object syntax is `key: value` separated by `,`

Ex:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  created(){
    axios.get('/ajax')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
    });
  }
}
```

P.S. I think understanding es6 modules would be helpful for you, so here is a link: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/