# i got this error: phrasing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved

Tags: html, css, jss

based on a web search i need to install a package but i cant figure out which one.
i tried using another writer (visual studio) and it shows no errors but the code does not work
i might be wrong any help is welcome thanks in advance 
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjpF7.png)
[error i got + the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjpF7.png)

the error i got: 
 phrasing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved
p.s.
it may be because my java wasnt updated but

i still got another error after i fixed that error so the code is not good.

Comment: Can you use let instead of cons

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706584/eslint-error-parsing-error-the-keyword-const-is-reserved