# I'm getting an error when trying to use 'const' in my userscript with Opera

Tags: javascript, syntax, constants, opera, userscripts

I'm able to use the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Edge (Chromium) with Tampermonkey and they all support using `const` in my userscript. However, for Opera 73.0.3856.284 with Tampermonkey 4.11.6120, I'm getting an error, "eslint: null - Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved". While I know I can use `var` or `let` I was wondering if there was a specific reason that was causing this error. My userscript is inteded to be cross-browser and I was hoping if there was a way to use const without getting this error. The image below is just a userscript I made with only const to show the error:

[image]

Edit: I ran a test userscript with this code:

```
const x = 2;
alert(x);
```

and the alert gave 2. Thus, I suspect that the code is running fine, but this is an internal error by Tampermonkey. In fact, I strongly believe this to be the case as I just saw this issue: https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/1099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is only a *linting error* for the in-browser editor provided by Tampermonkey, not a JavaScript runtime error. Your script should work just fine in modern versions of Opera; you can safely ignore the warning.

If you don't like the look of the warning, you can use an external script editor instead, eg, use:

```
// @require          file://C:/PATH_TO_FILE.user.js
```

in the metadata block, with no content after the metadata block. Write the code in `PATH_TO_FILE.user.js` instead.

If it hasn't already been reported, you could also raise an issue on Tampermonkey's github asking for a fix for the in-browser editor.

Answer (score 1):

The ESLint is set to old ECMAScript, although I don't get that error with default TamperMonkey 4.11.6120 install on Firefox.
It could be specific to Opera installation.

*TamperMonkey → Settings → Custom Linter Config*

ref: [Configuring ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)

```json
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    }
}
```

Previously ... [eslint: error Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706584/eslint-error-parsing-error-the-keyword-const-is-reserved)

**Update: comment from CertainPerformance**

It seems Opera installation has issues with above but the following works:

```json
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    },

    "env": {
        "es6": true
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, setting just the `parserOptions` version couldn't be parsed as valid on my Opera, but including [`"env": {
        "es6": true
    }`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42706706) worked.