# ERROR: Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved

Tags: javascript, css, web

i don't know why i'm receiving this error message can anyone help please ?

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
loginlink = document.querySelector('.login-link');
registerlink = document.querySelector('.register-link');

registerlink.addEventListener('click',()=> {wrapper.classList.add('active');});

loginlink.addEventListener('click',()=> {wrapper.classList.remove('active');});
```

i just folowed a vid and i don't know why it didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706584/eslint-error-parsing-error-the-keyword-const-is-reserved?

Comment: What system are you using, what is giving you the parsing error statement?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your browser does not surpport the syntax 'const', it is a little bit new. try using chrome (new version).