# how to exclude css files from eslint parser in React

Tags: reactjs, eslint, babeljs, eslint-config-airbnb

I need to exclude css files from the eslint parser.

Currently when I run `eslint src/**` this is checking all the files including css files. .
Please find below my eslintrc file contents.

```
module.exports = {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "airbnb",

    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "jsx-a11y",
        "import"
    ],
    "env" : {
      "browser": true
    }
    "rules": {
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    },

};
```

Comment: `.eslintignore` file to ignore styles would work nicely. maybe something like this: `*.css` or `src/**/*.css`. also, have you tried setting your eslint "root" to the folder of concern, that may simplify things?

Comment: Thanks you. It works!. could you also specify how to remove jsx-a11y/href-no-hash valdiations from eslint

Comment: my bad, "root" would actually be set to true, but only in the directory context where that is true, i.e. in "src/.eslintignore". see: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy

Comment: I just added *.css to the .eslintignore file

Comment: sweet. I'd check out the eslint/jsx-a11y documentation for that second question... they're bound to have an example of exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Using `src/**` as the path will miss any `.jsx` files in subdirectories inside of `src`. You can use `eslint --ext js,jsx src` instead and won't have to exclude CSS files in the eslintignore.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***.eslintignore*** file to ignore styles would work nicely. Inside, do something like this: `*.css`

**Here's a [good starting point](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-eslint-webpack-babel/) with these techs,** which I actually found while reading another, **[similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757885/setting-up-airbnb-eslint-with-react-and-webpack)**

Comment: Please include some contents of mentioned link, the links may be broken in futures times ;)

Answer (score 17):

Use `eslint --ext js,jsx src` instead. This allows ESLint to do its own traversal of the `src` directory, including files with `.js` or `.jsx` extensions.

Using `eslint src/**` and ignoring `src/**/*.css` will correctly exclude `.css` files, but it will miss any `.jsx` files in subdirectories inside of `src`.

#### Why?

Given this as an example

```
src
├── a.css
├── b.js
└── c
    ├── d.css
    ├── e.js
    └── f.jsx
```

- `eslint src/**` expands to `eslint src/a.css src/b.js src/c`. ESLint checks `src/a.css` and `src/b.js` because they were explicitly passed, then does its own traversal of `src/c` and lints `src/c/e.js`. This includes even non-js files directly within `src` and completely misses `.jsx` files in subdirectories of `src`.
- `eslint src` tells ESLint to do its own traversal of `src` with the default `.js` extension, so it lints `src/b.js` and `src/c/e.js` but misses `src/c/f.jsx`.
- `eslint --ext js,jsx src` tells ESLint to do its own traversal of `src`, including `.js` and `.jsx` files, so it lints `src/b.js`, `src/c/e.js`, and `src/c/f.jsx`.

Comment: In what file to add this line eslint --ext js,jsx src