# react typescript eslint plugin - The extension for the file (.svg) is non-standard

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have react with typescript.

I am trying to add some eslint to my project and I got this error during yarn lint

`(eslint src/** --ext .ts,.tsx")`

I also get some error on css

```
  0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: src/logo.svg.
The extension for the file (.svg) is non-standard. You should add "parserOptions.extraFileExtensions" to your config
```

**the same for .css**

my eslint based onthis post 
https://gist.github.com/1natsu172/a65a4b45faed2bd3fa74b24163e4256e

Answer (score 8):

Using `eslint src --ext .ts,.tsx` fixed it for me.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43742235/691083 for more background information.